# Uninstalling VirtualBox on Win10

Tags: windows-10, uninstall

I'm using an older laptop that runs Win10 while my normal machine is repaired. This machine cannot install Win10 updates until the VirtualBox software is removed. It is not listed under apps in Win10's list, nor is there an uninstall app listed within Win10's Startup menu. I tried the suggestion to run the installer which is supposed provide me with an uninstall option (VirtualBox-5.2.18-124319-Win is the version I was using), but that does not do so. Currently downloading latest version to see if that works.
I manually downloaded the Win10Upgrade 9252 from Microsoft's site as I had no luck with getting Win10's update to do it. This machine has sat idle for several months, thus no updates of any sort during that time. On running that Win10Upgrade file, it looked like it completed the downloading and got nearly thru the install when it stopped telling me I had to manually remove VirtualBox. As I had no luck in figuring out how to do that I had to cancel the Upgrade, which meant it backed itself out of whatever it was it had done and told me I had to start over.
Really don't want to re-install Windows as this laptop came with Win8. Getting it to update to Win10 the last time I had to do that was such a nightmare, it was why I bought the newer laptop 3 years ago. This machine is 6 years old.

Comment: No, that didn't work

Comment: Restart, Install VBOX, restart and then uninstall. If that does not work, you may need to reinstall Windows.

Comment: @IreneKraus - **What** didn’t work? How exactly did you determine that VirtualBox is blocking Windows Updates? [Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment